# Emacs: is there a way to pass a variable or a string into a M-x command?

Tags: emacs, ide, editor

I have a command called go-to-url that I call in my lisp code, which opens up a webpage, I just pass it a value string as so:

```
(go-to-url "www.yahoo.com")
```

However it'd be nice to use this function from the M-x command line. Is there a way to do that? Nothing that I have tried works

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you would use the interactive form:

```
(defun go-to-url (url)
  (interactive "sURL: ")
  (do-your-stuff url))
```

This way you can use `go-to-url` both in your lisp and with `M-x: go-to-url` and you'll be prompted for the argument.

See also my reply to your other question: [Emacs: Is there a way to create a interactive script using Emacs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235884/emacs-is-there-a-way-to-create-a-interactive-script-using-emacs)

Comment: Hey Daniel, thanks for the reply to both of my questions, this is really helpful, so I can kill 2 birds with 1 stone this way. Thanks a lot. I'll get back to the other question later when I have time hopefully later today. Just been swamped at work. Thanks though, this will save me a bit of my day :-)

Answer (score 1):

There is a function that does this already `browse-url', which will prompt you to browse the url at point or you can edit/create one.

For functions that take numeric arguments you can also use C-u then type the value you want passing to the command you execute.

Answer (score 0):

In [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles), during any minibuffer use (with completion or not) you can hit a key to [insert a string that was saved in  a variable or a register](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Inserting_a_Regexp_from_a_Variable_or_Register).

- For a register, hit <kbd>C-x r i</kbd> (as usual).
- For a string, hit <kbd>C-=</kbd>.

By default, the variable used is `icicle-input-string`, but if you use a prefix arg (i.e., <kbd>C-u C-=</kbd>) then you are prompted for the variable to use. Completion candidates include all string-valued variables.

You can save a string (e.g. a complex regexp) to a variable using command `icicle-save-string-to-variable`. Again, by default the variable is `icicle-input-string`, but with a prefix arg you are prompted for the variable.

You can also insert a string in the minibuffer at any time by hitting <kbd>M-:</kbd> and typing a Lisp sexp to evaluate.  The result is pretty-printed and inserted into the minibuffer.  (In Icicles, <kbd>M-:</kbd> opens a recursive minibuffer, and it pretty-prints.)